# How to modify parts of a State in Haskell

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I have a number of operations which modify a `System`. System is defined like this:

```
data System = Sys {
            sysId   :: Int,
            sysRand :: StdGen,
            sysProcesses :: ProcessDb,
            sysItems :: ItemDb
}
```

with e.g.

```
type ProcessDb = M.Map Int Process
```

But I also have some functions, which do not need access to the full System, but have types like this:

```
foo' :: (Process, ItemDb) -> ((Process, ItemDb),[Event])
```

Currently I gave them types like

```
foo: System -> (System, [Event])
```

But this is a needlessly broad interface. To use the narrow interface above in conjuntion with `System` I would have to extract a single `Process` and the `ItemDb` from `System`, run `foo'` and then modify `System` with the results.

This is quite some unwrapping and wrapping and results in more lines of code than just passing system as a whole and let `foo` extract whatever it needs. In the latter case, the wrapping and unwrapping is mingled with the actual `foo'` operation and I have the feeling that these two aspects should be separated.

I suppose I need some kind of lifting operation which turns a narrow `foo'` into a `foo`. I suppose I could write this, but I would have to write such a lifter for every signature of the narrow functions, resulting is lots of different lifters.

- is there an idiom how to solve such problems?
- is it worth bothering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a function which work on any State and which requires a "Lens" which captures the specfic transformation from the bigger State to the smaller State and back

```
focus :: (Lens s' s) -> State s' a -> State s a
focus lens ms'= do
    s <- get
    let (s', set) = lens s
        (a, s'')  = runState ms' s'
    put (set s'')
    return a
```

It allows me to write things like

```
run :: ExitP -> State SimState Log
...
   do
       evqs' <-focus onSys $ step (t,evt)
       ...
```

Where step operates on the "smaller" state

```
step :: Timed Event -> State Sys.System [EventQu]
```

Here onSys is a "Lens" and it works like this:

```
onSys :: Lens Sys.System SimState 
onSys (Sis e s) = (s, Sis e)
```

where

```
data SimState = Sis {
            events  :: EventQu,
            sisSys  :: Sys.System
```

I suppose the existing Lens libraries follow a similar approach, but do much more magic, like creating lenses automatically. I did shy away from lenses. Instead I was pleased to realise that all it takes was a few lines of codes to get what I need.

Comment: Yeah, `lens` would have you add a `HasWhatever s` context to constrain the state to something that "has" whatever piece of info you're looking for. A custom class could offer only a `Getter` or only a `Setter`.

Comment: Your function `focus` already exists in `lens`. It is [`zoom`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Zoom.html#v:zoom). It lets you embed the "smaller" `State` inside a bigger one.

Answer (score 3):

One common solution is to use a class, possibly created by the Template Haskell magic of [`Control.Lens.TH.makeClassy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html). The gist is that you pass in the whole `System`, but you don't let the function *know* that that's what you're giving it. All it's allowed to know is that what you're giving it offers methods for getting and/or modifying the pieces it's supposed to handle.

Comment: One reason why I want the narrow interface is that I can test the function more easily, because I don't need a full System at hand. The Classy method looks like it safely prevents the function from modifying things it is not supposed to modify, but I still have to provide a full System for testing. Am I right?

Comment: @MartinDrautzburg, you actually can add a dummy type that's an instance of the `HasProcess` and `HasItemDb` classes, say, and that doesn't have anything except those fields.